# Make generated classes internal

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

When you create an xaml page in Xamarin.Forms (say, `MyPage.xaml`), Xamarin generates a `public partial class MyPage` in a file called `MyPage.xaml.cs` to represent this page.

This imposes certain restrictions on the class: every class referenced in the signatures of this class' methods (as an argument type or as a return type) has to be `public` as well.

I am trying to get around this limitation: is there a way to make generated class `internal` or some workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WPF XAML you would do it with `x:ClassModifier="internal"` but unfortunately Xamarin.Forms xaml is another dialect. If you have a look at the Xamarin.Forms code generator you would see that it isn't using any configuration for the acces modifier of the generated class:   https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/2d9288eee6e6f197364a64308183725e7bd561f9/Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks/XamlGTask.cs

What you can do is to define a public interface and implement it in an internal class.

```
public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
{
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new Page1ViewModel();
    }

    public IWantToHideSomething Foo()
    {
        return new HiddenClass();
    }
}

public interface IWantToHideSomething
{
    void Bar(int x);
}

internal class HiddenClass : IWantToHideSomething
{
    public void Bar(int x)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```